# From a J1 visa to B2 USA visa

Tags: qatar-airways

Right now I have the J1 internship visa and I would like to apply for a B2 internship visa. How long would it take to process all those things and how long would it take before it will be approved? I am currently in the United States. Thank you.

Comment: A B-2 visa is normally for visiting (tourism, visiting people, etc...) and not for internships. What do you mean by a B-2 internship visa? You're already in the US; what are you looking to accomplish? Are you trying to change jobs?

Comment: Note that a U.S. visa is only for entry. If you are already in the U.S., you don't need a visa, you need a [change of status](https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/change-my-nonimmigrant-status-category/change-my-nonimmigrant-status).

Comment: OP has not returned to answer clarifications/questions from comments. Put on hold for now.